# How to raise a warning in Clojure

Tags: clojure, warnings

How do I raise a warning in Clojure?

Specifically, I've got a situation where I want evaluating a particular function call to raise an error while I'm running tests or trying to deploy a program, but I do want to be able to make that call successfully (ideally with a displayed message) while running at the REPL. (The [Common Lisp](http://www.gigamonkeys.com/book/beyond-exception-handling-conditions-and-restarts.html) solution here would be [`warn`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_warn.htm#warn)).

Is there a facility available that lets me do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's not really any such concept in Clojure. You would have to implement it yourself. There are a number of ways you could try to implement it, depending on your situation.

Simplest, perhaps, would be to define a dynamic var `*strict?*`, and set it to true normally, but false when you are in a repl. Then, define a function `(warn msg)` that checks the var and either throws an exception with that message or prints it as a warning.

Comment: Fair enough. I've packaged this into a library at https://github.com/inaimathi/trivial-warning for ease-of-use.